# bazel build error - tensor flow

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, java-native-interface, bazel

I am struggling to put my model in the Android studio.
In order to use my model in the Android studio, I also know that I need to put the libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar and libtensorflow_inference.so files into the assets folder in Android Studio.
So I used git to download the tensorflow library and use it to build .so and .jar files.
During the creation of the .so file I faced a problem that I could not solve.
I installed the SDK in the Android studio according to the procedure, and since I currently only support NDK version 17 in the studio, I installed version 12 externally and unzipped it.
[~/tensorflow/WORKSPACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AboA.png)

In order to build a bazel, I modified the content of WORKSPACE in the root folder of tensorflow as shown above. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zRcI.png)

But I had to face these terrible errors.
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvWoN.png) [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMwqJ.png)

To solve this problem, I changed the NDK location and installed another version of NDK. I tried to take other actions but the error did not go away. I have been working from yesterday to solve this problem. I need your help.

Comment: Please copy the output from the terminal to your question. Given somebody knows the solution, nobody else would find this question (and potential solution) later by searching for the exact same error message.

Comment: NDK r12 is really old. Have you tried with r15 or r16?

Comment: @Jin  No, but i tried ndk r17 . dont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `-std=c++11` flag.

Try passing this additional Bazel flag: `--cxxopt=-std=c++11`.